# How can I combine two arrays without creating an extra array level?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am combining 2 arrays into a new array using this code:

```
$newarray = array($array1, $array2);
```

The output is like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
     (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 1
     )
  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
                [1] => 7
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 20
                [1] => 10
            )
    )
)
```

But I want to change the structure, so the array will be like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
     (
       [0] => 3
       [1] => 1
     )
  [1] => Array
     (
       [0] => 4
       [1] => 7
     )
   [2] => Array
      (
        [0] => 20
        [1] => 10
       )
)
```

Is there any way to change the structure?

Comment: but tell us what codes you do so we can tell you what you need to change?

Comment: i just use `$newarray = array($array1, $array2)` to combining both array.

Comment: `<?php foreach($array2 as $arr){$array1[] = $arr;} echo "<pre/>";print_r($array1);` just do this  instead of `$newarray = array($array1, $array2)` and it will ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `array_merge` instead of `array`.

```
$new_array = array_merge([$array1], $array2);
```

Note that in order for this to work, `$array1` needs to be wrapped in another array: `[$array1]`. Otherwise `$array1` will end up as the parent of `$array2` instead of its sibling, and you'll get

```
[3, 1, [4, 7], [20,10]]
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you, you save my night! this seems also my fault for not carefully when i write my code :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote simple function that makes your array in manner that you want. Look at this code:

```
<?php

//array for testing
$inputArray = [
    [3, 1],
    [
        [4,7],
        [20,10],
    ],
];

function transformArray($inputArray)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach($inputArray as $key=>$elem)
    {
        if(is_array($elem[0]))
            $result = array_merge($result,transformArray($inputArray[$key]));
        else
            $result[] = $elem;
    }

    return $result;
}

//test result
print_r(transformArray($inputArray));
```

And result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 10
        )
)
```

**WORKING EXAMPLE: [CLICK](https://eval.in/629087)**